# MS SQL Server domain autorisation failed with JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to use JDBC driver `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` to connect to sql server with domain login using this url with no luck: `jdbc:sqlserver://hostname\TEST;database=test_db;UseNTLMv2=true;Domain=ORGLOT`
Getting error username/password doesn't match.

I tried to use `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` JDBC driver **and it works** with the following url: `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hostname/test_db;UseNTLMv2=true;Domain=ORGLOT;instance=TEST`.

But I can't use jtds because many methods not implemented.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong with `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`? How to make it work?

Sample code:

```
    public void connect() throws SQLException {
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://testserver\\TEST;database=test_db;UseNTLMv2=true;Domain=ORGLOT";
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setPoolName("pool");
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
//        config.setDriverClassName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        config.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        config.setUsername("test");
        config.setPassword("test");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        config.setIdleTimeout(10000);
        config.setMinimumIdle(100);
        config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(10000);
        config.setRegisterMbeans(true);
        config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        config.setValidationTimeout(10000);
        try (HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
             Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            String query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
            try (Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String name = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                    System.out.format("%s\n", name);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("OK" + connection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the code. I don't see any credential provided so I hope you define it to the driver manager. Provide a [mcve] please

Comment: _"Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong with com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver?"_ You are using jTDS properties instead of Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver properties. Check its documentation [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017)